# Print Different Output Values Corresponding to Duplicate Input in a Table?

Tags: duplicates, wolfram-mathematica, string-search

For example, `TableA`:

```
     ID1    ID2   
     123    abc
     123    def
     123    ghi
     123    jkl
     123    mno
     456    abc
     456    jkl
```

I want to do a string search for 123 and return all corresponding values.

```
    pp = Cases[#, x_List /; 
     MemberQ[x, y_String /; 
       StringMatchQ[y, ToString@p, IgnoreCase -> True]], {1}] &@TableA

    {f4@"ID2", f4@pp[[2]]}
```

Above, p is the input, or 123. This returns only one value for ID2. How do I get all values for ID2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To complement other solutions, I would like to explore the high-performance corner of this problem, that is, the case when the table is large, and one needs to perform many queries. Obviously, some kind of preprocessing can save a lot of execution time in such a case. I would like to show a rather obscure but IMO elegant solution based on a combination of `Dispatch` and `ReplaceList`. Here is a small table for an illustration (I use strings for all the entries, to keep it close to the original question):

```
makeTestTable[nids_, nelems_] :=
  Flatten[Thread[{"ID" <> ToString@#, 
         ToString /@ Range[#, nelems + # - 1]}] & /@ Range[nids], 1]

In[57]:= (smallTable = makeTestTable[3,5])//InputForm
Out[57]//InputForm=
{{"ID1", "1"}, {"ID1", "2"}, {"ID1", "3"}, {"ID1", "4"}, {"ID1", "5"}, 
 {"ID2", "2"}, {"ID2", "3"}, {"ID2", "4"}, {"ID2", "5"}, {"ID2", "6"}, 
 {"ID3", "3"}, {"ID3", "4"}, {"ID3", "5"}, {"ID3", "6"}, {"ID3", "7"}}
```

The preprocessing step consists of making a `Dispatch`-ed table of rules from the original table:

```
smallRules = Dispatch[Rule @@@ smallTable];
```

The code to get (say, for "ID2") the values is then:

```
In[59]:= ReplaceList["ID2", smallRules]

Out[59]= {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"}
```

This does not look like a big deal, but let us move to larger tables:

```
In[60]:= Length[table = makeTestTable[1000,1000]]
Out[60]= 1000000
```

Preprocessing step admittedly takes some time:

```
In[61]:= (rules = Dispatch[Rule @@@ table]); // Timing

Out[61]= {3.703, Null}
```

But we only need it once. Now, all subsequent queries (perhaps except the very first) will be near instantaneous:

```
In[75]:= ReplaceList["ID520",rules]//Short//Timing
Out[75]= {0.,{520,521,522,523,524,525,<<988>>,1514,1515,1516,1517,1518,1519}}
```

while an approach without the preprocessing takes a sizable fraction of a second for this table size:

```
In[76]:= Cases[table,{"ID520",_}][[All,2]]//Short//Timing
Out[76]= {0.188,{520,521,522,523,524,525,<<988>>,1514,1515,1516,1517,1518,1519}}
```

I realize that this may be an overkill for the original question, but tasks like this are rather common, for example when someone wants to explore some large dataset imported from a database, directly in Mathematica.

Comment: I don't see how this is obscure, but perhaps that is only because it is exactly how I would do it. +1

Comment: @Mr.Wizard For me, the interesting part was that, while `Dispatch` hashes the rules so that only the first one with identical l.h.s. fires (or at least, this is how I was thinking of it), it still works correctly with `ReplaceList`, which tries all the rules down the list, and also with no performance hit. I called it obscure because both `ReplaceList` and `Dispatch` are generally not so commonly used, and here we have their combination.

Comment: Perhaps I underestimated the complexity.  I do not have a Computer Science education, therefore I am not usually thinking about how something (`Dispatch`) works, only what it apparently does.  I have not really considered at length how `Dispatch` works, only that it apparently optimizes a list of rules.  Were you expecting that, among other things, `Dispatch` would internally eliminate rules two and three in: `Dispatch @ {1 -> x, 1 -> y, 1 -> z}` ?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, I thought this could be a possible scenario. I don't know exactly how `Dispatch` is implemented, but here is what the docs say: "... Rules such as `a[1]->a1` and `a[2]->a2`, which cannot simultaneously apply, need not both be scanned explicitly. `Dispatch` generates a dispatch table which uses hash codes to specify which sets of rules need actually be scanned for a particular input expression. ... ". Since I never before saw the combination of `ReplaceList` and `Dispatch` at work, I was not sure. B.t.w., I also don't have a CS education, something I am missing a lot presently.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that all the answers have missed the function that is almost specifically meant for situations like this, namely [Pick](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Pick.html). `Pick`returns those elements of a list for which the corresponding elements in a second are True. There is even a format  (which I'll  use) that has a third argument, the pattern to which the elements of the second list should be matched.

```
list1 = {"ID1", "123", "123", "123", "123", "123", "456", "456"};
list2 = {"ID2", "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "abc", "jkl"};

Pick[list2, list1, "123"]

==> {"abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno"}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
lis = {{"ID1", "ID2"},
  {"123", "abc"},
  {"123", "def"},
  {"123", "ghi"},
  {"123", "jkl"},
  {"123", "mno"},
  {"456", "abc"},
  {"456", "jkl"}}

(result = Cases[lis, {x_, y_} /; StringMatchQ[x, "123"] :> {x,y}]) // TableForm
```

[image]

If just want the RHS, then

```
Cases[lis, {x_, y_} /; StringMatchQ[x, "123"] :> y] // TableForm
```

[image]

Comment: You can simplify the expressions to `Cases[lis, {"123", _}]` and `Cases[lis, {"123", v_} :> v]`.

Answer (score 2):

This?

```
Last@Transpose[Cases[tableA, {ToString@p, _}]]
```

(as I cannot just cut and paste `tableA` from your question the way it is formatted, I didn't try it).

Answer (score 1):

TableA[[#[[1]], 2]] & /@ Position[TableA, 123]